# jsdom form submission?

Tags: node.js, automation, request, screen-scraping, jsdom

I'm trying to use the Node.js packages request and jsdom to scrape web pages, and I want to know how I can submit forms and get their responses. I'm not sure if this is possible with jsdom or another module, but I do know that request supports cookies.

The following code demonstrates how I'm using jsdom (along with request and jQuery) to retrieve and parse a web page (in this case, the Wikipedia home page). (Note that this code is adapted from the jquery-request.js code from this tutorial http://blog.nodejitsu.com/jsdom-jquery-in-5-lines-on-nodejs)

```
var request = require('request'),
    jsdom = require('jsdom'),

    url = 'http://www.wikipedia.org';

request({ uri:url }, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error && response.statusCode !== 200) {
    console.log('Error when contacting '+url);
  }

  jsdom.env({
    html: body,
    scripts: [
      'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js'
    ]
  }, function (err, window) {
    var $ = window.jQuery,
        // jQuery is now loaded on the jsdom window created from 'agent.body'
        $searchform = $('#searchform'); //search form jQuery object

    $('#searchInput').val('Wood');

    console.log('form HTML is ' + $searchform.html(),
      'search value is ' + $('#searchInput').val()

    //how I'd like to submit the search form
    $('#searchform .searchButton').click();
    );
  });
});
```

The above code prints the HTML from Wikipedia's search form, then "Wood", the value I set the searchInput field to contain. Of course, here the click() method doesn't really do anything, because jQuery isn't operating in a browser; I don't even know if jsdom supports any kind of event handling.

Is there any module that can help me to interact with web pages in this way, or in a similar non-jQuery way? Can this be done in jsdom?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @DeaDEnD
Thanks for the response.
I'm sorry if I was unclear, but the method I'm using isn't really the issue here - it's the environment, as emulated by jsdom. The way I'm using it, jsdom is simply parsing the HTML on the page and providing an interface to the resultant DOM.

Thus, no matter whether I use click() or submit(), it's not going to have any effect - those handlers don't exist, as jsdom sees things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to handle the POST request yourself like in the other answer, you can use an alternative to jsdom that does support more things in a browser.

http://www.phantomjs.org/

Comment: Thanks! This is the kind of thing I was looking for!

Now, to find a way to integrate PhantomJS and Node.. [link](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node) looks spot-on, if hacky and immature.

Thanks again!

Comment: PhantomJS is a browser, while jsdom is not, thus PhantomJS is much slower and more complex. Take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom - helps with node-phantomjs integration!

Comment: PhantomJS development is _suspended_

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with a nodejs library that will let you get a fully interactive client-side view of a web-page, but you can get the results of a form submission without too much worry.

HTML forms are essentially just a way of sending HTTP requests to a specific URL (which can be found as the `action` attribute of the `form` tag). With access to the DOM, you can just pull out these values and create your own request for the specified URL.

Something like this as the callback from requesting the wikipedia home page will get you the result of doing a search for "keyboard cat" in english:

```
var $ = window.jQuery;

var search_term = "keyboard cat";
var search_term_safe = encodeURIComponent(search_term).replace("%20", "+");

var lang = "en";
var lang_safe = encodeURIComponent(lang).replace("%20", "+");

var search_submit_url = $("#searchform").attr("action");
var search_input_name = $("#searchInput").attr("name");
var search_language_name = $("#language").attr("name");

var search_string = search_input_name + "=" + search_term_safe + "&" + search_language_name + "=" + lang_safe;

// Note the wikipedia specific hack by prepending "http:".
var full_search_uri = "http:" + search_submit_url + "?" + search_string;

request({ uri: full_search_uri }, function(error, response) {
    if (error && response.statusCode != 200) {
        console.log("Got an error from the search page: " + error);
    } else {
        // Do some stuff with the response page here.
    }
});
```

Basically the important stuff is:

1. "Submitting a search" really just means sending either a HTTP `GET` or `POST` request to the URL specified at the `action` attribute of the `form` tag.
2. Create the string to use for form submission using the `name` attributes of each of the form's `input` tags, combined with the value that they are actually submitting, in this format: `name1=value1&name2=value2`
3. For `GET` requests, just append that string to the URL as a query string (`URL?query-string`)
4. For `POST` requests, post that string as the body of the request.
5. Note that the string used for form submission must be escaped and have spaces represented as `+`.

Comment: Thanks for the highly-detailed response!
I'm well aware that this is one way to solve this problem, especially for a JavaScript-light site like Wikipedia.

However, I'm worried about those sites that are JavaScript-heavy, and, as such, might have ways of submitting forms beyond setting the action attribute.
For example, many sites set the form action to /#, and bind the handler that does the work to the button's onclick handler (using JavaScript).
If my script tried to submit such a form by hand, it'd follow the HTTP standard and send a request to URL/# instead of triggering the handler.